# Ion-segment value checks all

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Whenever I'm trying to put the value of `ion-segment`, all of them go on. See my image below for reference.
[image]

HTML

```
 <!-- Segment -->
            <ion-segment
              scrollable
              *ngIf="rating.Type === 'radio'"
              class="segment"
              value=" rating.Checked "
            >
              <ion-segment-button
                (click)="scoreButton(score, rating)"
                *ngFor="let score of rating.Scores"
                value="score.Score_id"
              >
                <!-- {{ score.Descriptions[0].Description }} -->
                {{ score.Score_id }}
              </ion-segment-button>
            </ion-segment>
```

scoreButton()

```
  scoreButton(score: any, rating: any) {
// To make sure only 1 score.Selected can be true.
    rating.Scores.map((ratingScore) => {
      if (score.Score_id == ratingScore.Score_id) {
        score.Selected = true;
      } else {
        ratingScore.Selected = false;
      }
    });
    rating.Checked = score.Score_id;
    console.log(score.Descriptions[0].Description, rating);
  }
```

Image of a rating so you can see the data behind it:
[image]

As you can see, I use the rating.Checked value to set the value of `ion-segment`

Answer (score 0):

`value` of ion-segment and ion-segment-button had to be between parenthesis. So `value="score.Score_id"` had to be `value="{{score.Score_id}}"`.